# How to get HTML form to post to itself in a non-public directory

Tags: php, html

I have my PHP files located in a folder that is one directory above the public directory. I have tried using the following, but have had no luck:

```
<form action="../Search/search.php" method="get">

<form action="" method="get">

<form action="search.php" method="get">
```

Can I get an html form to post to itself, in a non-public directory, or do I need to go about this another way?

Comment: What folder is your html in and what folder is your php in?

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith I should have been more clear. There is a simple login php form in the public directory that includes the search file in the "Search" directory. In the provided example, I'm trying to get search.php to submit to itself in the "Search" directory, which is on directory above the public directory.

Comment: So are you looking for this `Search/search.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP has to do the logic and use the $_GET[] variable.

The PHP file must be reached and called by the user session. Atleast 1 php file, say index.php or router.php must be inside a public directory in order to call 'search.php'.

You can for example route everything to routing.php and that way get to search.php, and/or by using a .htaccess file. The latter is not the easiest thing to do if you dont know how it works yet.

My suggestion. Just put the PHP-file in a public folder. It is safe*, for it will be executed server side.

*unless you are using insecure code

Comment: The problem is that I don't want users to be able to go to individual php files by typing in the url. I can use the router idea though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing is you understood that how the problem is happen, so save both html and php file in the same directory and call the php file like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action ="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> method="Post">
.
.
.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and save this page the same directory with php fle and run.